# Is there a conditional that runs if an if statement does not activate within a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.7

Making a simple program that swaps the location of numbers in a loop until they are in ascending order. I want the program to end when the if conditional is never activated within a instance of the for loop. Is there a shorter way to do this without the use of a while true/false or like?

```
while tf == True:
    for i in range(lisLen-1):
        tf=False
        if listy[i]>listy[i+1]:
             tf=True
             swap(listy, i, i+1)
```

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but `while tf == True:` is a verbose way of writing `while tf:`

Comment: Also when it finally does order the list properly, it'll most likely crash on the last index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the variable, and use `break` instead. Then you can use the `else:` clause to test this. That clause runs if the loop ended normally instead of with `break`.

```
while True:
    for i in range(lisLen-1):
        if listy[i]>listy[i+1]:
            swap(listy, i, i+1)
            break
    else:
        break
```